# sparql property paths and union

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to use SPARQL property paths on both sides of the UNION operator:

```
SELECT ?leaf
WHERE {
   {?root1 hasChild+ ?leaf} UNION {?root2 hasChild+ ?leaf}
}
```

But I'm getting a Virtuoso error:

> Variable '_::trans_subj_14_0' is used in subexpressions of the query but not assigned

However, if I leave out the plus sign at either side, the query works. eg:

```
{?root1 hasChild ?leaf} UNION {?root2 hasChild+ ?leaf}
```

or

```
{?root1 hasChild+ ?leaf} UNION {?root2 hasChild ?leaf}
```

Unfortunately, I would really like to get the leaves of both roots...
Can anyone, please, tell me what I'm doing wrong?